# Mapbox – Country Boundaries appears thicker in some places?

Tags: mapbox

Trying to style a Mapbox map to be very simple, just thin outlines of all the countries. I've almost achieved it, but it looks a bit weird as some lines appear thicker than others, what causes this – and is it fixable?

Also trying to add a border around the globe.

[Link to demo](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/persturesson/clggsngvt004j01quat6uf38c/draft.html?title=view&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicGVyc3R1cmVzc29uIiwiYSI6ImNsNjVmb2V3ODBzZWkzbXBkb2JwZHNydmwifQ.8eDKMpSnwRvSfQuDOwH1_w&zoomwheel=true&fresh=true#2.2/60.82/22.64)

Image from demo:
[image]

Goal:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The thicker lines are where boundaries touch one another.
You'll notice there are two borders on top of each other when you quickly zoom in and out. Look at the image below where the lines don't match one another. That's the US - Mexico border.

[image: border between two contries]

They look thicker because when it's zoomed out, you'll see a polygon simplification ([called Douglas-Peucker simplification](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-tiling-service/examples/natural-earth-countries-and-polygon-simplification/)) of both shapes. Each country will simplify the shape in a different way and the borders will be a bit apart one from the other, which you can clearly see in the image above.

To solve this, you can either [reduce the simplification](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-tiling-service/examples/natural-earth-countries-and-polygon-simplification/#using-the-tilesets-cli-to-generate-a-tileset) or use your own data source that doesn't add two lines in countries borders.